# How do i only allow integers and not words?

Tags: python

```
def Age():
    age = int(input("What is your age: "))

    if age != int(18):

        print("That's not an age.")

    else:

        print("Okay")
```

The whole purpose of what I'm trying to do is to make sure the person using this code is only able to put a number. If they put in words it would say that's not an age or something.. When I run this program it says "okay" if I put 18 but puts "that's not an age" when I type in 1.

Comment: You could use a try/except and try to convert to an integer, or use `isdigit`

Comment: Why are you checking `age != int(18)`? I think you mean to be using `int(age) != 18`

Comment: `try: int(input("what is your name: ")) except e: print("That's not an age")` Or something to that extent.